# Elasticsearch get all fields of type date

Tags: elasticsearch, go, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-query

I'm using olivere's elastic v.5 Go library (https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v5) for my Elastic queries. If I have an elastic mapping like this:

```
"mappings": {
        "boxes": {
            "properties": {
                "field1": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "field2": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "field3": {
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "field4": {
                    "type": "date"
                }
            }
        }
```

And I want to get a list of all fields that have type 'date'.

I've looked into [GetFieldMapping](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/olivere/elastic.v5#Client.GetFieldMapping) but that doesn't seem to have an option to filter the fields based on type.

I tried this:

```
elasticclient.GetFieldMapping().Index("someindex").Type("boxes").Field().Type("date").Pretty(true).Do(ctx)
```

That just gives me all the fields and their types. Is there a different syntax to do this? Thanks!